# System services (including SSH) not starting after editing /etc/resolv.conf and rebooting

Tags: networking, 18.04, ssh, dns

I am running Ubuntu Server 18.04.

I wanted to add a nameserver to my machine yesterday (remote soyoustart dedicated server) and I ended up deleting `/etc/resolv.conf` while trying to figure it out. I restarted my machine after I thought I'd fixed it but now none of my system services are starting (such as crontab, ssh, etc).

I managed to launch the rescue system (rescue64pro) and mounted my drive to `/mnt`, and `chroot`'d to the drive ubuntu was on.

I looked at the logs (using `journalctl --since "2019-10-23 12:30:00"`) but I can't see any errors in there. I compared the output here to a reboot that I had done a few months ago, and the reboot from a few months ago logged that ssh, crontab, etc were all running, however when I rebooted it today, there was no sign of any of these services. See the logs here: https://pastebin.com/bq4T4bkH

The machine itself is up, it responds to a ping, but all ports are closed.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are the content of /etc/resolv.conf now ? Do you have other servers you can check against if that looks correct ?

Comment: @SorenA I have a few other servers and I changed the resolv.conf to be the same as those: nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 213.186.33.99
search ovh.net

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this. Turns out it wasn't the /etc/resolv.conf at all, it was my /etc/fstab. I had to remove a rogue partition and it all booted fine.